# How to convert ZF2 Doctrine createQueryBuilder date field to timezone

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, query-builder

This is my query :

```
$casesData = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Cases\Entity\Cases')
    ->createQueryBuilder('cases')
    ->select('cases.CaseId',
        'cases.CreatedDate',
        'cases.LeadId',
        'cases.InquiryID',
        'cases.FirstName',
        'cases.LastName',
        'cases.CityDoc1',
        'cases.StateDoc1',
        'cases.SSN',
        'cases.Status',
        'cases.CaseManagerId',
        'users.first_name'
);
```

`cases.CreatedDate` is currently have "US Canada" timezone, now I want to convert base on timezone dropdown value, and I can't found any solution to convert timezone as per above query, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with query builder you can't change the time zone, you have to use loop as doctrine return datetime object than you can modify the time as you wish

```
foreach($data as item){
   $date = $item['CreatedDate']->modify('....')
}
```